# Using a scalar value function with declared variables to run through multiple records in a select statement

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-function

Good day,

I have a scalar value function that I used to determine a payment value (PMT function in Excel) in SQL Management Studio. I imported the following C# function:

```
using System;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Data.SqlTypes;
using Microsoft.SqlServer.Server;

public partial class FinancialFunctions
{
    [Microsoft.SqlServer.Server.SqlFunction]
    public static SqlDouble PMT(double r, int nper, double pv, double fv, int type)
    {
        double pmt;
        if (nper == 0)
            pmt = 0;
        else if (r == 0)
            pmt = (fv - pv) / nper;
        else
            pmt = r / (Math.Pow(1 + r, nper) - 1)
                * -(pv * Math.Pow(1 + r, nper) + fv);

        if (type == 1) pmt /= (1 + r);

        return pmt;
    }
```

The function is then called as follows in SQL:

```
DECLARE @LoanValue decimal(38,20)
DECLARE @APR decimal(20,15)
DECLARE @FullTerm int

SET @LoanValue     = VALUE of each individual loan
SET @APR           = INTEREST RATE for each individual loan
SET @FullTerm      = TOTAL TENURE for each loan

DECLARE @PMT decimal(38,20)

SET @PMT = dbo.PMT(@APR/12.0, @FullTerm, @LoanValue, 0, 0)

SELECT @PMT AS PMT
```

How would write a script to run through multiple loans with varying values, interest rates and durations?

Your assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: Not sure I understand. If you mean *"How do I use this is a `SELECT` statement?"* then you use it like any other function. `SELECT {Other Columns}, dbo.PMT(YT.APR, YT.FullTerm,YT.LoanValue,0,0) AS PMT FROM YourTable YT...`

Comment: Thank you @Larnu. I've been sitting in front of this laptop for so long that I forgot basic scripting. Appreciate the assist and pointing the obvious out to me sir.

Answer (score 1):

create a Table with all the values you need for the function.

```
  SELECT LoanValue, APR, FullTerm, fv, type , 
         dbo.PMT(APR/12.0, FullTerm, LoanValue, fv, type) as result
  FROM YourTable
```

Comment: Thank you kindly Juan, appreciate the assist with something so trivial.